# HA Jenkins setup

Tags: jenkins, high-availability, build-management

I am interested to setup high availability Jenkins environment with the following setup:

1. 2 active/passive jenkins masters that will use the same slaves
2. Proxy or load balancer which can perform automatic or manual failover.

I found out that apache mesos can do this type of work, but the setup is extremely complicated. I have a feeling that I am not the only who is facing this issue. What would be your recommendations for this setup? Preferably open source tools.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think gearman setup is also complicated. And you have to setup a gearman server to use gearman plug-in. and also what if gearnman server fails? so a quick solution is to use an active passive setup. just make another Jenkins master and rsync its home dir with active Jenkins server and keep its service in stop state , if primary master fails then just go and start secondary one.

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Gearman Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gearman+Plugin):

> we've decided to create the Gearman Plugin to support multiple Jenkins masters.  The gearman plugin was designed to support extra slaves, allow load balancing of build jobs, and provide redundancy.

or use [Enterprise Jenkins](https://www.cloudbees.com/products/cloudbees-jenkins-platform/team-edition) with [high availability feature](https://www.cloudbees.com/products/cloudbees-jenkins-platform/enterprise-edition/features/high-availability-plugin).